# Why dotnet core publish command does not copy uppercase extension file to output in centos 7

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a uppercase extension file in my dotnet core project. When I use dotnet publish, this file always not copy to the publish folder. But when I change its extension to lowercase, its can copy to the publish folder.

file.Config=> can copy to publish folder

file.config=> cant copy to publish folder

OS: CentOS 7

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
Release:        7.7.1908
Codename:       Core
```

---

**project content:** file extension with lowercase

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  129 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.Development.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   97 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.json
drwxrwxr-x. 3 yuze yuze   21 Dec 11 22:37 bin
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   25 Dec 11 22:37 Configurations
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   33 Dec 11 22:37 Controller
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  794 Dec 11 23:03 DotNetCoreDockerExample.csproj
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   34 Dec 11 22:37 Interface
drwxrwxr-x. 3 yuze yuze  260 Dec 11 22:37 obj
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  565 Dec 11 22:37 Program.cs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   33 Dec 11 22:37 Properties
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze 1362 Dec 11 22:37 Startup.cs
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze    3 Dec 11 22:37 test.config ## file
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   33 Dec 11 22:37 Utility
```

publish folder:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze     129 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.Development.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze      97 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.json
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze      25 Dec 12 07:55 Configurations
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  235447 Dec 12 07:55 DotNetCoreDockerExample.deps.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   10240 Dec 11 23:03 DotNetCoreDockerExample.dll
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze    1616 Dec 11 23:03 DotNetCoreDockerExample.pdb
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze     213 Dec 12 07:55 DotNetCoreDockerExample.runtimeconfig.json
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  761856 Jul 14 21:11 NLog.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   27648 Jan 16  2019 NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   35328 Jan 25  2019 NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze    4096 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   31232 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   58880 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze 9116672 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze       3 Dec 11 22:37 test.config # copied
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze     499 Dec 12 07:55 web.config
```

**project content:** file extension with uppercase

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  129 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.Development.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   97 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.json
drwxrwxr-x. 3 yuze yuze   21 Dec 11 22:37 bin
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   25 Dec 11 22:37 Configurations
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   33 Dec 11 22:37 Controller
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  794 Dec 11 23:03 DotNetCoreDockerExample.csproj
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   34 Dec 11 22:37 Interface
drwxrwxr-x. 3 yuze yuze  260 Dec 11 22:37 obj
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  565 Dec 11 22:37 Program.cs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   33 Dec 11 22:37 Properties
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze 1362 Dec 11 22:37 Startup.cs
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze    3 Dec 11 22:37 test.Config # file
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze   33 Dec 11 22:37 Utility
```

publish folder:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze     129 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.Development.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze      97 Dec 11 22:37 appsettings.json
drwxrwxr-x. 2 yuze yuze      25 Dec 12 08:09 Configurations
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  235447 Dec 12 08:09 DotNetCoreDockerExample.deps.json
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   10240 Dec 11 23:03 DotNetCoreDockerExample.dll
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze    1616 Dec 11 23:03 DotNetCoreDockerExample.pdb
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze     213 Dec 12 08:09 DotNetCoreDockerExample.runtimeconfig.json
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze  761856 Jul 14 21:11 NLog.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   27648 Jan 16  2019 NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   35328 Jan 25  2019 NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze    4096 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   31232 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze   58880 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
-rwxrw-r--. 1 yuze yuze 9116672 Nov  7  2018 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yuze yuze     499 Dec 12 08:09 web.config
```

Comment: What platform? windows, MacOS or Linux?

Comment: Note that in your second line you are missing the dot between file and txt (you have written file       txt) .   It's important to get your question as correct as possible so people can see what if anything is causing things not to work - I'd recommend editing it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file system is case sensitive in Linux distributions. So that is probably at the heart of the confusion. Your csproj file has "test.**C**onfig" for the included file in the project. So that is the command part that `dotnet publish` sends on your CentOS Linux distribution.

To the Linux case sensitive file system, "test.**c**onfig" does not exist :).